# Kotlin Comparator Compilation Error in IntelliJ

Tags: kotlin

Using Kotlin 1.2.41-release and given a `List<Pair<Int, Int>>`, the following code generates a compilation error in Intellij, although Gradle command line build works.

`sortedWith(compareBy({ it.first }, { it.second }))`

```
Cannot choose among the following candidates without completing type inference.
public fun <T> compareBy(vararg selectors: (???) -> Comparable<*>?): kotlin.Comparator<???> defined in kotlin.comparisons
public fun <T> compareBy(vararg selectors: (Pair<Int, Int>) -> Comparable<*>?): kotlin.Comparator<Pair<Int, Int>> defined in kotlin.comparisons
```

How can I fix this?

**Edit**:

```
edges
  .map {
      it.either.run {
          val p = this
          val q = it.other(this)
          val min = min(p, q)
          if (min == p) p to q else q to p
      }
  }
  .sortedWith(compareBy({ it.first }, { it.second }))
  .toList()
```

where, `edges` is `Iterable<Edge>`

```
class Edge(private val v: Int, private val w: Int, val weight: Double) : Comparable<Edge> {
    val either: Int
        get() = v

    fun other(vertex: Int): Int {
        return if (v == vertex) w else v
    }

    override fun compareTo(other: Edge): Int {
        return weight.compareTo(other.weight)
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Edge(v=$v, w=$w, weight=$weight)"
    }
}
```

Comment: That's rather weird, that `sortedWith` call works for me. Is your Kotlin plugin in IntelliJ also up-to-date? You can check by going to `Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates -> Check for updates now`.

Comment: @zsmb13 It’s up-to-date with the latest stable version I posted above

Comment: If your Kotlin version set in `build.gradle` is also the same, this should be working fine. Perhaps try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`.

Comment: @zsmb13 Same minor version, but the plugin has a build number. Will try invalidating cache

Comment: @zsmb13 Invalidating cache didn't help.

Comment: It works for me as well. Can you paste the whole code, i.e. how you build list of pairs?

Comment: I copy-pasted your code, just adding `val edges: Iterable<Edge> = listOf()` and it compiles and runs just fine. And I'm using the same Kotlin version

Comment: Maybe somehow you have two Kotlin runtimes in the project? You could also try to specify type explicitly like `compareBy<Pair<Int,Int>>`